# Dictionary of words on Kibana Visualization

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I'm a recent user of Kibana and I'm facing a problem I couldn't find the solution. As you can see below on the Kibana Snapshot, I've a visualization and I want to translate the words there. For example, instead of **General_Positive_Feedback** I'd like something like **Positive Feedback**, instead of **General_Negative_Feedback** I'd like to show **Negative Feedback**, etc.

[image: Kibana Snapshot]

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your Kibana version is higher than 6.4, then you can use the `Static Lookup` formatter in the index patterns configuration.

Just go to the index pattern of the index you want to edit, type the name of the field, in your case `intents.keyword`, and click in the pencil icon on the right side, you will see something like the image below.

[image: static lookup]

In the format drop down menu, choose `Static Lookup`, in the `Key` field type the original value of your field, for example `General_Positive_Feedback`, and in the `Value` field type what you want to show on kibana if this value appears, in your case it will be `Positive Feedback`, do it for each value that you want.

This does not changes your data, only the visualization.

If your Kibana is older than 6.4 you will need to use some painless script to change the visualization value or reindex your data with this value already change by your ingestion pipeline.

Comment: Thanks so much @leandrojmp, that was what I was looking for..!

Answer (score 1):

How about using scripted fields function with painless language in kibana.

You can change words, calculate something, etc.

for example, you can make script like this:

```
String intent = params['_source']['intents'];

if (intent == "General_Positive_Feedback") {
    return "Positive Feedback";
} else if (intent == "General_Negative_Feedback") {
    return "Negative Feedback";
} else {
    return intent;
}
```

Then, the result is look like this.

[image: Discover result image]

[image: Aggregation result image]

Please check below

- How to create scripted fields in kibana: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/scripted-fields.html
- Painless language guide: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/7.5/index.html
- Scripted fields using painless example: https://www.elastic.co/blog/using-painless-kibana-scripted-fields

Comment: Thanks occidere and Brendan. That was a good answer, it helped me to learn a new feature and it's another option to solve my problem! Thanks a lot.